# The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state - AoAG - SQL Server 2012 - 15 minute interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, service-broker

I receive this error message in SQL Server error log every 15 minutes. I have setup AOAG on this server. The database option "Service Broker - Broker Enabled" is turned on for the Blackberry related databases and MSDB databases on this instance. Blackberry support mentioned they do not need this enabled. I have other AOAG instance and they do not receive this error.

Please share your wisdom in this regard. I have not used service broker yet and did not find a similar post on stack exchange from my search.

Thank you

Comment: What patch (version) is sql server 2012 running on ? Seems like you would need latest SP/CU. Check [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22316/8783) answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](http://sqlserverdbahelp-naresh.blogspot.com/2016/01/the-service-broker-endpoint-is-in.html),

> It’s a default behavior. The message will show when AlwaysOn
>   availability group Listener is created and SQL Server binds the
>   Listener’s IP dynamically. There is no method to suppress the message.
>   These messages are informational message and do not cause any harm and
>   can safely be ignored.

That link also gives a query to see which databases do and do not have brokers enabled:

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled, name  FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a service broker endpoint in a test environment out of curiosity where these messages were occurring and this resolved the issue.

```
CREATE ENDPOINT BrokerEndpointTest
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP (  LISTENER_PORT = 4022  )
FOR SERVICE_BROKER (AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS  );
GO
```

Answer (score -5):

Please ensure `[NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]` is a sysadmin on all nodes of the availability group.

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
GO
```

Comment: You should add details about why this is required.